# Javascript Auto run a function

Tags: javascript

I want my function "thing()" to run automatically from the page load. At the moment it is activated by a button.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="thing()">Greeting</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function thing() {
  var greeting;
  var time = new Date().getHours();
  if (time < 10) {
    greeting = "Good morning";
  } else if (time < 20) {
    greeting = "Good day";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good Evening";
  }
  document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = greeting;
}
```

I am very new to java script so as simply please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = thing();
```

will run the function automagically!!

Comment: should be more correct writing `window.addEventListener('load', thing);` as there may be more than one function to run

Comment: `window.onload = thing();` Didnt Work But `window.addEventListener('load', thing);` did. Thanks

Comment: It doesn’t work because `windows.onload = thing()` assignes the *result* of calling `thing()` to `window.onload`.